# Reading border color of input text from theme in flutter

Tags: flutter

How can I read border color of input text from theme

I want to set my `Container`'s border color equal to input's border colors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default value of input text border is primary color which you can access using theme as following.

```
Scaffold(
        body: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(color: Theme.of(context).disabledColor)),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
      child: TextFormField(
      ),
    ));
```